# Why aren't these strings displayed in separate lines?

Tags: c#, string

write the contents of person in a file

FirstName: Abcd

SecondName: Tsfsdfs

For this I wrote a sample application

```
namespace BinaryStream
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter binWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\happybirthday.txt");
            string name = "Sachin";
            string secondname = "tendulkar";
            string wishes = "happy birthday";

            string firstname = string.Format("FirstName: {0} \n", name);
            binWriter.Write(firstname);
            string sn = string.Format("SecondName: {0} \n", secondname);
            binWriter.Write(sn);
            binWriter.Close();          
        }
    }
}
```

IF I open the contents in the notepad, the strings are not displayed in the next line
What is the reason for this? Is the format part is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use WriteLine, not Write.  Write does not put a linefeed\cr at the end of the line.  Placing \n in the text only places a linefeed, and does not place a cariage return.

Comment: He's trying to put linebreaks in the string itself. (Although WriteLine would be a better way of doing this...)

Comment: It's actually the carriage return (`\r`) that's missing; the linefeed is alread in his format strings.

Comment: Also, he'd see those newlines without \r w/ wordpad and not notepad

Comment: @payo - that's because wordpad has code to replace the standalone lf's with cr/lf, notepad does not.

Comment: @MystereMan how it does it is another issue, on a side note, how do you know it literally injects \r's, and doesn't just render the \n sufficiently?

Comment: @payo - because when the document is resaved, it replaces the \n's with \r\n's

Answer (score 3):

You require both a carriage return and a line feed. You only have a line feed. Replace your \n with \r\n and you'll see it correctly in notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that you need a combination of a Carriage Return (CR) and a Line Feed (LF) character, not just the LF.

So - in your code, replace the \n with \r\n

Comment: which is one is correct \r\n or \n\r. As john said it should be \n\r for the newline in windows

Comment: It's \r\n - as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539801/reminder-r-n-or-n-r

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you are creating a binary file rather than a text file. This is probably confusing Notepad.

Besides in C# the \n means LF only, you must use \r\n (CR - LF).

Just write this:

```
string[] lines = {"FirstName: Abcd", "SecondName: Tsfsdfs"};
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\happybirthday.txt", lines);
```

Comment: This isn't a C# thing, it has to do with the program reading the file.  Notepad requires \r\n, winword deals with \n or \r\n just fine, as do many other programs.

Answer (score 0):

New line is `\n\r` in windows. But some programs are intelligent enough to understand just `\n`. Others, like notepad - are not.

Comment: Basically, instead of using the string escape character, use `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: Actually, newline is \r\n, not \n\r.  It does make a difference.