# MS Excel doesn't detect UTF-8 encoding

Tags: excel, utf-8

MS Excel is not able to detect the UTF-8 encoding and act accordingly. This leads to display garbled foreign language characters. So as a workaround i go to Data->Import->From text and choose the corresponding file and select the UTF-8 encoding format and delimiter as (,) and proceed will show foreign characters properly. But in such a case it won't show the new line character ("\n") properly, if a cell value contains a new line character it get break and displayed in the next line. Someone please suggest a solution for this problem.

Comment: Use a decent spreadsheet application. ;-P Seriously though, will you have to support Excel *among other application*, or are you targeting Excel exclusively?

Comment: In open office it's working fine. I need a solution for this in Excel

Answer (score 0):

To put a new line in Windows you should use \r\n to **\retur\n**.

Comment: Is `\retur\n` supposed to be a mnemonic? I like it.

Comment: Yes! i take from [this thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539801/reminder-r-n-or-n-r)

Comment: when you write your text file you insert chr(10)+chr(13) ? or your files come from external origin and you should use "as is". Can you send a example two rows of data ?

Comment: @deceze `retu\r\n` seems like a better mnemonic