# Line feed - Is \n\r valid?

Tags: windows, carriage-return, linefeed

In an Windows environment:

**\r (Carriage Return)** moves the cursor to the beginning of the line without advancing to the next line.

**\n (Line Feed)** moves the cursor down to the next line without returning to the beginning of the line.

According to these definitions, `\r\n` and `\n\r` could be used interchangeably, am I right?

It should not matter whether you go `down then left` or `left then down`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539801/reminder-r-n-or-n-r) is similar, but it tells what everyone is used to, instead of explaining why.

Comment: You would be right if you are sending output to a teletype.  But nobody uses a teletype anymore.  \r\n is the correct sequence, you risk unexpected output when you reverse it.  Like an extra linefeed in a program that tries to be resilient against conflicting Windows, Apple and Unix line-endings.  YMMV, little point in having to answer that support phone call.

Comment: I saw `\n\r` in my company's codebase... so I'm going to change it

Comment: Who voted for close as opinion-based? The other question I'm talking about deserves this. Mine is objective. Please explain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the context.

If you're controlling an actual typewriter: Yes, they're the same.

If you're talking about file formats or network protocols: No, you have to use the right sequence of bytes (regardless of the reason those bytes were chosen originally).